# How to calculate weights of a perceptron with vector output?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I have a perceptron which takes two inputs with weights accordingly

```py
i1 = [i1_0, i1_1] 
w1 = w1  
i2 = [i2_0, i2_1] 
w2 = w2
```

My output for this perceptron is `p[p0, p1]`.

How do I calculate new weights during backpropagation?

I always did it for i1 and i2 being only numbers not vectors and in that case I would use

```py
delta = CorrectResult - (MyCurrentResult * Derivative)
newWeight = oldWeight + (learninRatio * delta * p)
```

Of course if I tried to count it that way I would have weight being a vector eg `w1 = [w1_0, w1_1]` too but I need it to be just a number.
Should I calculate `w1_0` and `w1_1` and then use some mean value or is there a different way?